# Double array only stores ints

Tags: c, casting, int, double

I have this code here that I think should work, and it does! except for the fact that though I've declared a pointer to an array of type double, it always stores int, and I don't know why.

first, I have this struct and it is defined like this:

```
struct thing {
    int part1;
    double *part2;
};
```

then I initialize the thing by saying `struct thing *abc = malloc (sizeof(struct thing))` and `part1 = 0` and `part2 = malloc(sizeof(double))`.

then, I try to set specific values at specific positions in the array of double. This works fine with integers, but when I tried 0.5, it set the value to 0. when I tried 2.9, it set the value to 2. I really don't know why it does this. code for setValue looks like this:

```
struct thing *setValue (struct thing *t, int pos, double set){
    if (t->part1 < pos){ // check to see if array is large enough
        t->part2 = realloc (t->part2, (pos+1) * sizeof(double));
        for (int a = t->part1 + 1; a < pos + 1; a++)
            t->part2[a] = 0;
    t->part1 = pos;
    }
    t->part2[pos] = set; // ALWAYS stores an integer, don't know why
    return t;
}
```

-- Edit: So there is nothing really mallicious about this part; but here's the rest of my code JUST IN CASE:

Relevant functions that operate on my struct thing

```
#include "thing.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct thing *makeThing(){ // GOOD
    struct thing *t = (struct thing *) malloc (sizeof(struct thing));
    t->part1 = 0;
    t->part2 = malloc (sizeof(double));
    t->part2[0] = 0;
    return t;
}

struct thing *setValue (struct thing *t, int pos, double set){
    if (t->part1 < pos){ // check to see if array is large enough
        t->part2 = realloc (t->part2, (pos+1) * sizeof(double));
        for (int a = t->part1 + 1; a < pos + 1; a++)
            t->part2[a] = 0;
    t->part1 = pos;
    }
    t->part2[pos] = set; // ALWAYS stores an integer, don't know why
    return t;
}

double getValue (struct thing *t, int pos){
    if (pos <= t->part1){
        return t->part2[pos];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef THING_H
#define THING_H

struct thing {
    int part1;
    double *part2;
};

struct thing *makeThing();
struct thing *setValue (struct thing *t, int pos, double set);
double getValue (struct thing *t, int pos);

#endif
```

main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "thing.h"

int main (void)
{
    struct thing *t = makeThing();
    setValue (t, 1, -1);
    setValue (t, 1, -2);
    setValue (t, 10, 1);
    setValue (t, 3, 1.5);

    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 0));
    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 1));
    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 2));
    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 3));
    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 4));
    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 5));
    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 6));
    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 7));
    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 8));
    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 9));
    printf ("%g\n", getValue (t, 10));

    return 0;
}
```

On my computer, this prints out:
0
-2
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
1

EDIT: Turns out that when I compile it via codeblocks, it works...

Ultimately, I am confused.

Comment: It would be a good idea to accept some answers. :-)

Comment: Could it be because of your printing statement?

Comment: yep, how are you printing the values?

Comment: I don't think so - I've used `printf ("%g\n", t->part2[pos]);`, gives integer values back. I've made sure that 0.5 or 2.9 gets put in by printing 'set' at the  beginning of the loop, and it definitely is taking in 0.5 or 2.9 or whatever double value I give it.

Comment: [Your code works well at ideone](http://ideone.com/VPDK2i).

Comment: Ok... so does that mean my compiler is bad, or...? Because It prints and stores integers on my computer.

Comment: @user1459732: we need more code to identify the problem.

Comment: Where is `setValue()` called? Is the prototype visible there? Have you compiled with warnings enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Double converts to int in C?

No, it doesn't. When you assign a `double` value to an object ot type `double` there is no conversion whatsoever.

Your problem is not in the code you've shown; it is somewhere else (the way you print, some stupid `#define`, some other thing).

Oh! And you really should make sure the `realloc()`s work. Otherwise, instead of an error, users may get a slightly erroneous value...

*As I said in a comment, [your code works as expected at ideone](http://ideone.com/VPDK2i).*

Comment: I accepted the answer because I thought I had messed up a define in the header - but when I changed it it still didn't work, so I expanded the code.

Comment: Are you using separate compilation? Meaning are you only compiling the source code with `main()` and linking to an old version of the functions that deal with `struct thing`? I can't see anything wrong in your code (and it works for me with gcc 4.7.1). The cast to the return value of malloc() is redundant (provided the `#include <stdlib.h>` is in place); I prefer to use the object itself as argument to the `sizeof` operator to avoid errors with wrong types (`sizeof *t->part2` for instance).

Comment: So, basically, I figured out that if I compile it with an IDE (in this case, CodeBlock), it works, but when I try to compile from the command line, it does not work. :/

Comment: Delete everything, in all directories, except the source code (.o files, .exe files, .lib files, ..., maybe keep .bak and/or .prj files ...) and try again with the command line compiler. I suspect you're using mismatched source and object files.

Comment: Sorry for late accept. Esssentially your last comment there was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have messed up your format specifier in your printing. Be sure to have the correct specifiers for the correct data types.

I know that happened to me sometimes when I changed data types in my Objective-C code. :)

Comment: `%g` is correct, it prints a double in standard or scientific notation, depending on its magnitude.

Comment: %f also prints a double, but always in standard notation (100000000, c.f. %g would print that as 1e8)